# Why "fiber optic[s]" and not "optic fiber"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

The preferred term to talk about those fast network cables (which are called "fibre optique", literally optic[al] fiber, in French) seems to be "fiber optic[s]".

Grammatically there are two ways I can understand it:

- fiber optic: an optic that's made of fiber
- fiber optics: the optical characteristics of fiber

None seems to match the meaning I feel it's trying to convey, i.e. a fiber-y material that can transport optical information (i.e. light).

If I were to follow the standard adjective-before-name order we find in English, I'd get something resembling "optical fiber" or "optic fiber".

Why is it like that? Is it a special case or are there other words "made" like this?

Comment: *Fiber-based optics*? There is no reason why one noun can't modify another noun. The one doing the modifying is called an attributive noun.

Comment: Heh heh. Why do the folks in the UK insist it is maths where folk in the USA will say math?

Comment: @puppetsock Because the word is "Mathematics", not "Mathematic". Did I miss a joke?..

Comment: @JasonBassford that's the thing I don't get. The thing could be called "optic-stuff-carrying fiber", because its "main" component is fiber. It's just a fiber that carries optical stuff. To me, "fiber-based optics" sounds like you're doing optics with fiber material, which is the other way around

Comment: @Jorgomli Yeah, but you wouldn't call a **condo**miniu**m** a condom.

Comment: puppetsock - for the same reason we write 'fibre', I dare say.

Comment: @EddieKal I don't see how that has anything to do with correctly abbreviating a plural word with a plural abbreviation. There's no such thing (to my knowledge) as a single mathematic. It is always "mathematics." So logically, that makes the abbreviation, "maths."

Comment: @Jorgomli When a joke is just a joke... Jokes aside, as you say, "there is no such thing as a single mathematic". So seeing "maths" as an abbreviation of a plural noun might be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @EddieKal Oh, since this isn't a forum, jokes aren't expected here. I'm not seeing why "maths" instead of "math" would be a stretch. Where else in English do we abbreviate a plural as its singular form? Especially if there is no singular form?

Comment: @Jorgomli A lot can be said about the uncanniness from taking "mathematics" as a plural noun. Without trying to privilege one English speaking tradition over another, I'd like to point out that "mathematics" is an academic subject (only plural in form) just like economics and linguistics, and almost invariably takes a singular verb. See [this discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51955/is-mathematics-singular-or-plural). Where else? Economics is **econ** to its majors.

Comment: @Eddie Kal, idk about the rest of this comment, but econ classes are prefixed as ECON in school, example ECON 101. That's why it's referred to as that.

Comment: @Jorgomli I am not sure what you are getting at. Econ is a [word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/econ) in its own right.

Comment: @EddieKal this'll be my last comment because this conversation is pretty useless to this question. Your link even says "informal - Economics as an academic subject." Which is exactly what I said above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's not quite correct to use "fiber optic" or "fiber optics" as a noun for the cable itself, though it may be a common error or informal usage.

*Optics*, as we know, means "the area of science that studies light".  Thus I interpret *fiber optics* as "the area of science that studies the transmission of light through fibers".

You could speak of *fiber-optic cable*, meaning "cable that operates on the principle of the transmission of light through fibers". Or you could speak of *optical fiber*, meaning "fiber that is related to light (presumably for transmitting it)"